# How do I get the IDs of everybody with specific rows/values in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table that consists of the following:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|     CustomerID      |     Product ID   |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         101      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         102      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         103      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         101      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         105      |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I only want to select unique Customer IDs where they have exactly the product IDs of 101, 102, 103. I don't want to pull in customer with ID 2 because, although they have Product ID 101, they don't have the correct combination.

Comment: I suspect that this question has been answered before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT CustomerID 
FROM myTables
WHERE ProductID IN(101,102,103)
GROUP BY CustomerID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ProductID) = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Your request should be like :

```
Select CustomerID 
From your_table_name 
Where ProductID=101 And CustomerID In 
(Select CustomerID From your_table_name Where ProductID=102 And CustomerID In
(Select CustomerID From your_table_name Where ProductID=103));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use following approaches to get your desired results

Using aggregation

```
SELECT CustomerID 
FROM table1
GROUP BY CustomerID
HAVING SUM(ProductID = 101) /* SUM(ProductID = 101) = SUM(CASE WHEN ProductID = 101 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 */
   AND SUM(ProductID = 102)
   AND SUM(ProductID = 103);
```

Using EXISTS

```
SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID 
FROM table1 A
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM table1
  WHERE ProductID = 101 AND CustomerID = A.CustomerID
) AND EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM table1
  WHERE ProductID = 102 AND CustomerID = A.CustomerID
) AND EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM table1
  WHERE ProductID = 103 AND CustomerID = A.CustomerID
)
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fad7c7/3)